# Should I use client_secret in a native, public downloadable application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I've read a lot about the different flows (authorization code, implicit, hybrid and some extensions such as PKCE). Now I'm on the authorization code flow with PKCE.

PKCE ensures the initiator is the same user as the users who exchanges the authorization code for an access token. That is nice and OK.

When using this flow without a client_secret (which is recommended for SPA/Javscript applications) there is no warranty that the client is the known/original client. So, the 'consent' the user gave, is of no value. uhh?

I am working on a nativate client (a public downloadable binary). A secret cannot be considered confidential when baked in the binary, it can be decompiled for example.

Now I'm in dubio. What is better, bake the secret in the binary so that there is some extra layer of assurance the client is the known client or stop asking for 'consent' and give the same client_id to the whole world, only relying on the user-credentials.

Or is there something wrong with my story?

Answer (score 1):

Very good question and made me realise a gap in my understanding. It is the role of the redirect uri to deal with this risk. In the web / https case the only hack that could work would be to edit the hosts file of the user. I'm the native case it is less perfect and your question is covered below. Generally our best bet is to follow recommendations / standards - but they have plenty of problems! https://web-in-security.blogspot.com/2017/01/pkce-what-cannot-be-protected.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

To others reading this case I've read a lot more.
Client impersonation is not easy fixable.

RFC8252 seems to be the most applicable article with recommendations for native apps - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252
"Claimed ‘https’ scheme" is mentioned as the best solution (IOS, Android and maybe UWP apps).

Since I'm working on a native Windows, non-UWP application I can't use this. As far as I can see the "Web Authentication Broker based on the app SID" is possible for my situation.

The other method is to accept the client as not known/identified and ask for 'consent' every time the client would access personal data.